# How do i fast press enter in vim editor

Tags: vim

It is a naive question. Because the enterkey in my keyboard is too far, so it's unconvience to press it.
Is there a key that is similar with enter in vim, so i could press it alternative enter.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, perhaps consider remapping? e.g.  `:inoremap <F1> <Enter>`?

Comment: How large is your keyboard that the Enter key is "too far"?

Answer (score 2):

I personally use a remap key that is below:

for enter -> `inoremap kk <enter>`

for escape -> `inoreamp jj <esc>`